# Avoiding application level instrumentation and let Istio do the job

Tags: spring-boot, instrumentation, otel

I integrated my Spring Boot application (a couple of REST service calls) with sleuth-otel and everything is working fine.
Still I was wandering if I can replace this application level instrumentation with Istio proxy level header enrichment (seen Istio FAQ "Why can't Istio propagate headers instead of the application?" but I don't get the point).

Thank you for the clarification!

Istio proxy level instrumentation also for the tracing service observability

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In Istio official website (https://istio.io/latest/about/faq/#how-to-support-tracing) the documentation says: "However, in order for various trace spans to be stitched together for a complete view of the traffic flow, applications must propagate the trace context between incoming and outgoing requests." . My question is: why Istio can't do this propagation instead of the application?